# How to create a custom Widget with custom conditions

Tags: magento2, blocks, adminhtml, widgets, custom-block

I need to create a custom widget using custom conditions to show a product list in the home page. I have to show the option to add multiple inputs in the widget form to set conditions that I need.

When Group Id = 1, show Category Product 5.

I need the string Widget in the content like:

```
{{widget type="My\Module\Block\Widget" category_by_group="3=15,4=81,0=31" title="Title of widget" }}
```

The value `3=15` in the `category_by_group` field means that if Customer Group is 3, the category id will be 15, but I have to type the Group Id and the Category Id and separate them manually with comma.

I have this XML file:

> My/Module/etc/widget.xml

```
<widget class="My\Module\Block\Widget" id="custom_products">
    <label>Product Carousel</label>
    <description>Carousel of product based on a category.</description>
    <parameters>
        <parameter name="title" sort_order="0" xsi:type="text" visible="true">
            <label>Widget Title</label>
        </parameter>
        <parameter name="category_by_group" xsi:type="text" visible="true">
            <label translate="true">Categories by customer groups</label>
        </parameter>
    </parameters>
</widget>
```

Is there a way to add multiple inputs dynamically?

Answer (score 2):

Add the below to `widget.xml` it will provide you with an interface so you can easily define the conditions of products to appear in your widget

```
<parameter name="products" xsi:type="conditions" visible="true" required="true" sort_order="145" class="Magento\CatalogWidget\Block\Product\Widget\Conditions">
    <label translate="true">Products</label>
</parameter>
```

There are other parameters you can pass in, check out `Magento/CatalogWidget/etc/widget.xml` for more information

Then your class `My\Module\Block\Widget` should ideally extend `Magento\CatalogWidget\Block\Product\Widget` as it will contain the methods required to build the collection of products.

If you get stuck displaying the collection on the front end, check out `Magento_CatalogWidget::product/widget/content/grid.phtml`

And finally, I'd recommend adding the below to your `module.xml` (if it isn't already there)

```
<sequence>
    <module name="Magento_CatalogWidget"/>
</sequence>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead to pass following string from widget.

- category_by_group="3=15,4=81,0=31"

just create one Custom Variables in admin path is:

- system -> Custom Variables

And add "3=15,4=81,0=31" in Variable under Plain Value option & retrieve this custom_variable in block class.

You can update it in admin in future instead to update it in widget call.

Let me know if you still have any issue in it.